# NodeJS What is my current Google Cloud Function Name?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I want to use the name of the current Google Cloud Function to drive some logic.  How do I determine what my Google Cloud Function name is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According with [this page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically), there is a set of environment variable automatically set on Cloud Function.

Select the right one according with your language runtime

- `FUNCTION_NAME` in nodeJS 6 or 8
- `K_SERVICE` in nodeJS10+