# NodeJS How to determine if running in Google Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

How do I tell if my process is running in a Google Cloud Function?

Comment: Not sure if there's a in-built property, but you can always initialize your function with some env and check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 checks in mind:

- Firstly, if the Cloud Function env variables are set (your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388694/nodejs-what-is-my-current-google-cloud-function-name/62389408#62389408))
- Secondly, you can check if the metadata server answer by [performing a get request to it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata). *Don't forget the header (`Metadata-flavor: google`).* If you get a Http status code 404, you aren't on Cloud Function.

Comment: I am running NodeJS 10 so I am using if (process.env.K_SERVICE).  Also for whoever comes later, __filename does not give the service name.